# iPhone SDK: Open file in my app

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, uiactionsheet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

I have seen in a few different places that when clicking a link, it asks me if I want to open that file in a number of apps, such as iBooks, FileMagnet, or other apps.

Is there a way in the SDK, that when someone clicks on a link in Safari or an email to a .kml or .gpx file, that I can ask if they want to open it in my app?